Examples of groups with a unique maximal normal subgroup.
I'm looking for groups that have exactly one maximal normal subgroup.
Definition: A subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is a maximal normal subgroup if both $N\unlhd G$ and whenever $N\subseteq M\subseteq G$ for $M\unlhd G$, we have either $M=N$ or $M=G$.
The only examples I have so far are the so-called one-headed groups.
Definition: A group $G$ is one-headed if it has a proper normal subgroup that contains every proper normal subgroup of $G$.
NB: According to here:

simply saying that there is a unique maximal normal subgroup is a somewhat weaker statement [than being one-headed].


The group $S_n \times \mathbb{Q} (n \ge 5)$ is an example of group with unique maximal normal subgroup $A_n \times \mathbb{Q}$ but not one-headed. In general, the direct product of a one-headed group with a divisible group is a not-one-headed example.
